# Upload Images to my Flickr account with Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

Hi guys i am looking to upload to the my flickr account using only javasscript/Jquery. Problem is the API documentation of Flickr seems absolutely hopeless. It shows the service to call for image upload but no real working examples as such. Any tutorial / github account / working example for this would be really helpful.. 
Has anyone worked on this before? 
Kindly help

Comment: Good + API documentation = contradiction in terms.

Comment: search `flickr api examples` in your favourite search engine results in a wealth of information

Comment: you need to have `api_key` , `auth_token` and `api_sig` then you can make a post request to `https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/` with type `multipart/form-data` to upload the image